# How to convert list item to multidimensional array in c#?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a single list of data like

```
List 0 index Contains : BlockId = 438001,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077
UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238047,ZoneId = 1018
List 1 index contains : BlockId = 438001,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077,UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238048,ZoneId = 1018
List 2 index contains : BlockId = 438002,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077,UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238138,ZoneId = 1018
```

And now I want to create a multidimensional array according to that like 
`public List<int>[][] arrayList{get;set;}`

I need to convert list data to multidimensional array list like

```
[0]
[0] -> Count 1 -> 438001  --> Showing blockId
[1]-> Count 3 -> 238047,238048 --> showing villageId


[1]
[0]->count 1 -> 438002
[1]->count 2 -> 238138
[2]->count 3-> 0 --> showing townId



var data = user.getUserRolebyUserId(userId);
var blkList = data.GroupBy(x => x.BlockId);
List<int>[][] lst;
foreach (var item in data.GroupBy(x => x.BlockId))
{
    List<int>[][] array = [item.Key,item.Select(x => x.VillageId).ToList(), item.Select(q => q.TownId)];
}
```

I am trying to applying this but it's showing me error for Invalid Expression.
So How can I convert list into multidimensional array ?

Comment: `List<int>[][]` this is **not** a *multidimensional* array, its a *jagged* array of `List<int>`

Comment: Aside from what _TheGeneral_ said, `... = [something, something, something];` is not even valid C# syntax. I guess it perhaps indicates the need to spend some more time with C# tutorials covering the basics of how to create, initialize and use arrays and collections....

Comment: I am trying to `List<int>[][] array = new int[][] {item.Key, item1.VillageId, item1.TownId };` but it's also not converting it.

Comment: You declare a variable of type `List<int>[][]` but then try to create and assign a `int[][]` instance to it. (An `int[][]` is not even remotely the same as nor is it convertible to `List<int>[][]`) What? That doesn't make a lick of sense...

Comment: @elgonzo,
how can I add simple int[][] to List<int>[][] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dictionary :

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Location> locations = new List<Location>() {
                new Location() { BlockId = 438001,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077, UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238047,ZoneId = 1018 },
                new Location() { BlockId = 438001,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077,UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238048,ZoneId = 1018},
                new Location() { BlockId = 438002,DistrictId = 438,TownId = 0,UserId = 1077,UserTypeId = 4,VillageId = 238138,ZoneId = 1018 }
            };

            Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = locations
                .GroupBy(x => x.BlockId, y => y.Items)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public class Location
    {
        public int BlockId { get; set; }
        public int DistrictId { get; set; }
        public int TownId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
        public int VillageId { get; set; }
        public int ZoneId { get; set; }

        public List<int> Items {
            get { return new List<int> { BlockId, DistrictId, TownId, UserId, UserTypeId, VillageId, ZoneId }; }
            set {;}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dictionary is new for me. can I able to convert this Dictionary into List<int>[][] ?

Comment: You really have three levels of arrays (not two) since you are using a GroupBy.  A GroupBy creates a two dimensional array [key][List].  In your case the List is an array of attributes (BlockId, DistrictId, TownId, ...).  So do you really want to remove the attribute names like "BlockId" when you say List<int>[][]?

Comment: Yes actually I need List of Int which will contains two array in which first one will contains villageId and second one will contains townId.
I am searching for convert dictionary to List<int>[][] but almost are using only int[][].